# Updating Object in ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I've written this code and everything seems to be correct but unfortunately its not giving the correct units sold. im trying to find out if the salesperson ID exists and update that record. Sometimes it prints the right information and sometimes it does not.

```
 import java.util.*;
     public class salesPerson {

       //salesPerson fields
       private int salespersonID;
       private String salespersonName;
       private String productType;
       private int unitsSold = 0;
       private double unitPrice;

       //Constructor method
       public salesPerson(int salespersonID, String salespersonName, String productType, int unitsSold, double unitPrice)
       {
         this.salespersonID = salespersonID;
         this.salespersonName = salespersonName;
         this.productType = productType;
         this.unitsSold = unitsSold;
         this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
       }


       //Accessor for salesPerson
       public int getSalesPersonID(){
           return salespersonID;
        }

       public String getSalesPersonName(){
           return salespersonName;
       }

       public String getProductType(){
           return productType;
        }

       public int getUnitsSold(){
           return unitsSold;
        }

       public double getUnitPrice(){
           return unitPrice;
        }

       public double getTotalSold(){
            return unitsSold * unitPrice;
        }

       //Mutoators for salesPerson
       public void setSalesPersonID(int salespersonID){
           this.salespersonID = salespersonID;
       }

       public void setSalesPersonName(String salespersonName) {
           this.salespersonName = salespersonName;
        }

       public void setProductType(String productType){
           this.productType = productType;
        }

       public void setUnitsSold(int unitsSold){
           this.unitsSold = this.unitsSold + unitsSold;
        }

       public void setUnitProce(double unitPrice){
           this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        }

            public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ArrayList<salesPerson> salesPeople = new ArrayList<salesPerson>();
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean newRecord = true;
            int salespersonID;
            String salespersonName;
            String productType;
            int unitsSold = 0;
            double unitPrice;

            do{
                System.out.println("Please enter the Salesperson Inoformation.");
                System.out.print("Salesperson ID: ");
                salespersonID = userInput.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Salesperson Name: ");
                salespersonName = userInput.next();
                System.out.print("Product Type: ");
                productType = userInput.next();
                System.out.print("Units Sold: ");
                unitsSold = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Unit Price: ");
                unitPrice = userInput.nextDouble();

                if(salesPeople.size() == 0) 
                {
                    salesPerson tmp = new salesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice);
                    salesPeople.add(tmp);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i=0; i < salesPeople.size(); i++) {
                        if(salesPeople.get(i).getSalesPersonID() == salespersonID)
                        {
                            salesPeople.get(i).setUnitsSold(unitsSold);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            salesPerson tmp = new salesPerson(salespersonID, salespersonName, productType, unitsSold, unitPrice);
                            salesPeople.add(tmp);
                        }
                      //System.out.println(salesPeople.get(i).getSalesPersonName());
                    }
                }

                System.out.print("Would you like to enter more data?(y/n)");
                String askNew = userInput.next();
                newRecord = (askNew.toLowerCase().equals("y")) ? true : false;

            }while(newRecord == true);



            for(int i=0; i < salesPeople.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(salesPeople.get(i).getSalesPersonName() + ": "+salesPeople.get(i).getUnitsSold());
            }

        }

     }
```

Comment: It would be useful to get more information on what is the input, and what's the output against what's expected. Given that my 2¢, in Java the convention is to name classes with capital letters, so `SalesPerson` is a better name. Second you may want to keep your `SalesPerson` organized in a Map, where ID is a key and value is a `SalesPerson` object (for faster look-up).

Answer (score 1):

This method is probably wrong:

```
   public void setUnitsSold(int unitsSold){
       this.unitsSold = this.unitsSold + unitsSold;
    }
```

Replace it by:

```
   public void setUnitsSold(int unitsSold){
       this.unitsSold = unitsSold;
    }
```

You also have a problem on your main() method: The for creates a new SalesPerson instance for each element that has a different id from the one you've received on the input.

It's not related with your problem, but you should always (and I mean ALWAYS) start the name of Java classes with capital letters.